# Unable to send hit to Google Analytics from Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I am struggling to send hits to Google Analytics from Apps Script in Google Sheets using the code below. I built and tested the hit using Google Analytics Hit Builder and pasted the data into here. I get a 200 response from the server but the hit never appears in Google Analytics. If I change the destination URL to a test server the data is received and looks OK. This should be a straight forward post. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

```
function simpleHit(){

  data = 'v=1&t=event&tid=UA-xxxxxxx-2&cid=0757d62f-9f96-4083-bc08-6b03116d4fe9&ec=Test%20Category&ea=Test2%20Action&ev=2'

  var url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect'

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : data
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log('response: ' + response.getResponseCode())
}
```

Comment: Hello @user11985045, are you sure you are passing the right format for the `data`? Are you able to replicate the request using other tools? (such as Postman) Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13, I'm pretty sure. I built and tested the data using google's hit builder and literally cut and pasted the data into my code. Sending the same payload using Postman worked.

Comment: Have you tried using the ```Content-type``` parameter in your **options** object just to make sure this is also not the issue? Check [this out](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters_1) to see more details about this.

Comment: Problem solved - Turns out that the address pool used by Google for URLFetchApp traffic were being treated as bots by GA. After disabling the Bot filtering option in GA it worked. Thanks to those that offered suggestions.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please post that comment along with the information of what did work in an answer to this question so that anyone having the same issue can easily see the answer? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - For others who experience this it turns out that the address pool used by Google for URLFetchApp traffic were being treated as bots by GA. After disabling the Bot filtering option in GA it worked.